# How I can fix it Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\authentication\Online Catering Reservation System.php on line 29

Tags: php

```
<?php 
session_start();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Register Login and Logout User</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <h1> Register, Login and Logout user php mysql</h1>
</div>
<?php 

    if (isset($_SESSION['message'])){
        echo "<div id='error_msg'>" .$_SESSION['message']. "</div>";
        unset($_SESSION['message']);
    }

    ?>


<h1>Home</h1>
<div><h4>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION ['username']; ?></h4></div>
<div><a href="Logout.php">Logout</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my code how can I fix it

> Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\authentication\Online Catering Reservation System.php on line 29

Comment: You need to check that is session exists and then print welcome and logout line.

Comment: Your $_SESSION-array doesn't have a key named 'username'.

Answer (score 2):

Replace these lines

```
<h1>Home</h1>
<div><h4>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION ['username']; ?></h4></div>
<div><a href="Logout.php">Logout</a></div>
```

with

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])){ 
<h1>Home</h1>
<div><h4>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION ['username']; ?></h4></div>
<div><a href="Logout.php">Logout</a></div>
<?php }else{ ?>
//add code to redirect to home page
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to test the existence of the index first:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])
    echo $_SESSION ['username'];
?>
```